# Просмотр изменений сцены Unity3d в истории git репозитория

Tags: git, unity3d

Проект в Unity3d. Сцена включает в себя ряд заготовок, в том числе UI c Canvas.
При изменениях в самой сцене (например был изменен UI в Canvas'e) показано, что был изменен файл сцены, но не показано как именно.
Вопрос: есть ли какая-то возможность просматривать изменения в рамках коммитов, когда правилась сцена?

Comment: да вроде можно... файлы же в гит отправляются как текстовики.. а  там всё видно

Comment: Использую для просмотра клиент, в котором ничего не отображается для файлов сцены. Возможно, это проблема у самого клиента. Раз вы говорите, что возможно, попробую другими средствами проверить.

Comment: Да, если что-то было изменено, закомичено и запулено, то это не может быть не отражено в diff. Если конечно были сделаны настройки все необходимые (типа Force text и вот этого всего)

Comment: Была настройка включена скрытого бинарника - показывало, что был изменен некий бинарный код. И все. А когда поставил настройку, чтобы не скрывало - пишет теперь, что файл слишком большой. Но попробую другой клиент. Возможно, именно используемый мной не подходит.

Comment: Оказалось, что после правки настроек редактора нужно было и просматривать не из используемого мной клиента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Edit` → `Project Settings` → `Editor`

1. `Version Control Mode` → `Visible Meta Files` ✔
2. `Asset Serialization Mode` → `Force Text` ✔

Comment: Я так и сделал чуть раньше. Но клиент писать начал, что файл слишком большой. Проверил в другом месте - показывает правки. Т.е. ваше решение + другой клиент.